# How to make container div height of page at all times, with no content overflow?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple webpage where there is a centered div with content in it. So far I've had a fairly easy time, but I've hit one roadblock: when the browser window is shorter than the main content, the content "spills out," (example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8yeJ.jpg)

I've looked at quite a few tutorials / similar questions, but I can't seem to find one that quite meets my requirements:

- Keeps container centered (most solutions use *position:fixed*, which usually makes the container div align to the left side of the page
- Keeps the container the height of the window, even after resizes
- Allows scrolling when the window isn't tall enough (*overflow:hidden* usually eliminates the scroll bar, so only part of the content shows

Here is my code:

(css)

```
#container {
        width: 900px;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto auto auto auto;
        padding: 1px;
        background-image: url('img/light_toast.png');
    }
#mainHeader {
        margin: 30px 30px 10px; 
        padding: 0px;
    }
#mainContent{
        margin: 0px 80px 0px 80px; 
        padding: 1px;
    }
```

(html)

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="mainHeader">
            <h1 id="msg" align="center" style="margin: 0 auto">Header Text</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="mainContent">
            <p id="par1"></p>
            <p id="par2"></p>
            <p id="par3"></p>
            <p id="par4"></p>
            <p id="par5"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to emulate the browser window? Try just centering your content block (`margin: 0 auto` works for most browsers) and let the browser handle scrolling, etc.

Comment: When I add that to the mainContent style, all it does is make the text spread out to the edges of the container div, it still overflows. If I add it to the container style, I still get the overflow error.

Comment: Try `width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;`  I'm afraid from your screenshot I can't figure out what you are going for - do you have an example you are trying to emulate maybe?

Comment: I suppose in a way I'm trying to emulate https://www.thinkgeek.com/ wherein all the stuff in the center div scrolls, but the background stays static. However, that div is the height of the content. I'd like mine to be the height of the browser window, and the content inside of it scrolls.

Comment: Try just fixing the background image: `background: url(...) fixed 0 100%;` I think that's how thinkgeek does it (though they have some tricky transparency stuff going on with the robots/zombies)

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky and has lots of techniques that may or may not work for your particular case.

Try:

- http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm
- http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/
- http://wickham43.net/backgroundsfullheight.html
- http://www.positioniseverything.net/thr.col.stretch.html

Comment: The issue I run into with all of these is that the use of overflow: hidden does what it is supposed to, but in hiding all the text that overflows it gets rid of a major chunk of the webpage if the browser is too short.

Comment: Are you  looking for `overflow: scroll`?

Comment: This helped, and I have modified my CSS to mostly work based off this. The issue I'm having is that the overflow scroll doesn't show all of the content, it cuts off the bottom paragraph. http://pastebin.com/stqy5JqV

Comment: In general try not to specify the `height` of elements; rather, let the content inside them determine the height of the container.